# Confused about signalr thread safety?

Tags: signalr

I have a blazor server app, where each user connects with signalr to a hub. The hub uses shared state among all users. Is this thread safe?

Also, if i split the code in multiple hubs, which again share state among all hubs/users, is this also thread safe?